# Disable Mozaik / TinyMCE editor for email templates in SuiteCRM 7.6.6

Tags: email, templates, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Since my upgrade from SugarCRM to SuiteCRM I notice that when I edit email templates, I get the Mozaik block editor on top of the TinyMCE editor and this generates a lot of html code in the email template. I like to keep my emails simple, but even my plain HTML is being modified as soon as I save it.

Is there a way in SuiteCRM version 7.6.6. to disable the Mozaik editor. I know that in later versions this is a choice in the email settings, but here not yet, and I don't want to upgrade further, risking my working system.

In which part of the code this Mozaik editor is being called? And how to disable this?